# sticky footer for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a website using Bootstrap 3 (http://www.patrickmanser.ch/fnws) and I want do code a sticky footer. I applied the codes used in the Bootstrap 3 examples, adjusted them to my sizes. It works perfectly on a desktop monitor. If you switch to mobile sized screens, however, the footer overlaps the content. I'm guessing, it is because the size (height) of the footer changes aswell, as I'm using the grid system there. You can look at the source code (main.css), but I think the most important parts are these:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 237px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#page-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    color: #999;
}

.copyright {
    background-color: #222;
    min-height: 50px;
    color: #666;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

I have no idea how to solve this, or if it even can be solved properly. Any hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in your .copyright, it's your "min-height: 50px;"

If you change that to just "height: 50px;", it would reduce the push up against the top body content.  You need to adjust that so that you're not forcing it to accommodate your line-height of 50px;

Either that, you can also reduce your line-height to something shorter like 20px.  That would also reduce the push up to your body content when you're in mobile.

I would actually try reducing the line-height first to see if that fixes it and then delete the "min "to see if that helps.